Custon user form conflict in variables
Trying to use custom forms to use info from models, for signup, login, etc.

models.py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# error is in CustomUser, next line
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32, unique=True, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)


forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
#   UpdateView

from django.views.generic import CreateView


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CreateView
        fields = ('username', 'email')


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CreateView
        fields = ('username', 'email')


class UserAdmin(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CreateView
        fields = ('username', 'email')

Error displayed after successfully running runserver.:
ERRORS: antelope.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'antelope.CustomUser.groups' clashes wit h reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'. ups'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'antelope.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.gro antelope.CustomUser.user_permissions:
(fields. E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'antelope.CustomUser.user _permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'antelope. CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'aut h.User.user_permissions'. auth.User.groups:
(fields. E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor f or 'antelope.CustomUser.groups'. ups'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'antelope. CustomUser.gro auth.User.user_permissions:
(fields. E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'antelope.CustomUser.user_permissions'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'antelope. Cust omUser.user_permissions'.
